# how to force OkHttp on Android 11 to send ssl client cert auth with TLS 1.3

Tags: android, authentication, ssl, okhttp

We need to perform certificate based client authentication to a server accepting only TLS 1.3 connections.
The server is using Apache 2 and HTTP 1.1 and is configured to *allow* client cert auth but not to enforce it because some resources require client auth while others don't.

We're using OkHttp 4.9.1 on Android 11 to perform the call and we're following the standard docs on how to perform client auth: https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-tls

The server however replies with: 403 (auth renegotiation not allowed)

This is in line with TLS 1.3 specification which does not allow auth renegotation unless agreed upon during the initial handshake.

So far we've debugged the connection and inside OkHttp the class RealConnection and it actually performs the Handshake without negotiating a client cert.

Our research so far indicates that this might be due to the server using OPTIONAL ssl client auth but this is not somethign we can change so....

1. Is there any other option we can pass during OkHttp initialization to force it to perform the initial handshake using the client cert?
2. in case OkHttp is not a viable option is there any other HTTP client implementation which would allow us to force such authetnication during the initial handshake?

Comment: have you tried any other HTTP client other then OkHttp ? usually the default Java(=android) implementation has broader compatibility (even if it lacks configuratino options and flexibility of OkHttp)

Comment: URLConnection with the proper keystore and trustmanager gives the very same 403 error anbd we don't expect the standard URLConnection to be configurable enougth for this purpose, moreover we're already using OkHttp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optional client certificate authentication is no different from required client certificate authentication from the perspective of the client. All what the client sees is a CertificateRequest and as a response it will send some certificates (leaf and chain), which might also be an empty list of certificates. It is up to the server to decide if this is acceptable, i.e. optional simply means that the server accepts that the client sends an empty list of certificates.

The problem thus is not optional or required client certificates, but that the server has not requested a certificate at all in the initial TLS handshake and likely only requests a certificate when accessing a specific path (the requested path can only be seen after the initial handshake). With Apache this is typically the case if client certificate is not requested in the server global configuration but instead in a path specific .htaccess file. Fix would be to move the requirement at the level of the domain and not the path only.

Answer (score 2):

Create a HandshakeCertificates object using its builder. You'll need your private key, client cert and any intermediates on the client side.

The client will also need a root certificate for your server to trust it. The builder has a function to use the built in certificate authorities for that if you like.

```
  private OkHttpClient buildClient(
      HeldCertificate heldCertificate, X509Certificate... intermediates) {
    HandshakeCertificates.Builder builder = new HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
        .addTrustedCertificate(serverRootCa.certificate());

    if (heldCertificate != null) {
      builder.heldCertificate(heldCertificate, intermediates);
    }

    HandshakeCertificates handshakeCertificates = builder.build();
    return clientTestRule.newClientBuilder()
        .sslSocketFactory(
            handshakeCertificates.sslSocketFactory(), handshakeCertificates.trustManager())
        .build();
  }
```

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/1ce86f35a9d957bae711fb81cec60abe9f43dda0/okhttp/src/test/java/okhttp3/internal/tls/ClientAuthTest.java#L126

Comment: thnaks but setting the socketFactory and the trustManager is essentially the same thing as the tutorial which I mentioned and as expected it did not resolve